# Filepond custom server functions

Tags: filepond

[image]

The docs only mention an `abort` parameter in the return object for custom functions. Are there any other parameters or callbacks too? What if I want to do some task after the custom function such as `process` is done?

Answer (score 0):

There are not other methods to return in a custom process method. If you want to run other functions on the file you can do all of that in the process method and accumulate the progress. You could for example upload to multiple locations and only call `load` when the final upload completes. An alternative is to run additional functionality in the `onprocess` callback.